# How to get the unique of datatable under specific condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable, unique

If i have datatable like this :

```
pic_id  selected

  1        1
  1        1
  1        0
  2        0
  2        0
  2        0
```

---

I want to get Unique (pic_id)

but under the condition that at least one of the pics(with the same id) has `selected` value =1

For the previous example

I want the result like this :

```
 1    1
```

Comment: there is no difference between "1       jo      1" and "1       moh     1" so your desired output does not make sense. why would you want one arbitarily?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to order by `emp_name` and keep the first of each pic_id-group? Do you want to get unique pic-id's or do you want unique `DataRows` as result? Is `selected`  the field you want to filter by in general or does it belong to your group-filter logic? The question is yet not clear.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = dataTable.Select("selected = 1");

var uniqueList = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: hmmm, thanks but i don't want the `selected = 1` for all the pics ,i want to get the unique where for each specific pic one in the group (them)of the has selected = 1.
may be u will get what i mean from the example result

Comment: @just_name this gives you what you want. i've modified my answer. it will only take rows that have selected = 1 and then provide you with the distinct using linq